# Integrate $\int_0^1 \sin^{-1}{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Integrate $\int_0^1 \sin^{-1}{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}dx$

I tried to put $x=\tan\theta$, which gives
$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} {\sin^{-1}({\sin^2\theta}})\sec^2\theta d\theta$, but I don't know how to proceed after this.
Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Did you miss a factor $\sec^2 (\theta)$?

Comment: @xbh yeah corrected that.

Comment: @HappyMittal Sorry, but should it be times $\sec^2(\theta)$ rather than divides it?

Comment: Again, why downvote this? This question seems to be hard to start. It is possible to be clueless about this.

Comment: yeah I agree this is a hard integral upvoted it

Comment: @xbh yeah my bad, approved the edits. This question on the top of it, looked easy to me, but after lots of attempts, I am still clueless about it.

Comment: @xbh Agreed, edited and upvoted.

Comment: look at my solution it is long but elegant

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title. I've edited the question in now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}} $$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\arcsin(u)}{2u^{1/2}(1-u)^{3/2}}\,du $$
which (pretty incredibly) can be managed by integration by parts. It boils down to
$$ \frac{\pi}{6}-\int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}}\cdot\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du $$
then to
$$ \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}+\log(2+\sqrt{3})-\sqrt{2}\log(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}\approx 0.219563.$$

Comment: How did you compute the last integral?

Comment: @Szeto: by letting $u=\sinh^2 v$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

You might know the property that $$\int_a^b f(x) dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} (x) dx=bf(b)-af(a)$$

Using this we get $$\int_0^1 \arcsin \left( \frac {x^2}{1+x^2}\right) dx+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{6}} \sqrt {\frac {\sin x}{1-\sin x}} dx=\frac {\pi}{6}$$

Therefore $$\int_0^1 \arcsin \left( \frac {x^2}{1+x^2}\right) dx=\frac {\pi}{6}- \int_0^{\frac {\pi}{6}} \sqrt {\frac {\sin x}{1-\sin x}} dx$$

Now for the integral on right hand side use the  substitution $u=\sin x$ which will lead you to a very simple integral $$\int_0^{\frac 12} \sqrt {\frac {u}{1-u}} \frac {du}{\sqrt {1-u^2}}$$ Which can be solved as stated by Jack D'Aurizio

Answer (score 3):

integration by parts $${\int}\mathtt{f}\mathtt{g}' = \mathtt{f}\mathtt{g} - {\int}\mathtt{f}'\mathtt{g}$$

$$f=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)   \space  and \space g'=1  $$

$$f'=\dfrac{\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-\frac{2x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}}$$
$$g=x$$

$$I=x\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-\frac{2x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_1={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-\frac{2x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_1=2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x\left(x\left(x^2+1\right)-x^3\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_1=-2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x\left(x^3+x\left(-x^2-1\right)\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I_1=2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I_1=2{\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}-\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I_1=2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x-2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_2={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I_3={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

now solving $I_2$
substitute $u=\sqrt{2} x$ thus  $\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u$

$$I_2=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I_2=\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+1}+u\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$I_2=\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2x^2+1}+\sqrt{2}x\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

now solve $$I_3={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$x=\dfrac{\tan\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\sec^2\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I_3={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sec^2\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\tan^2\left(u\right)}{2}+1\right)\sqrt{\tan^2\left(u\right)+1}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$$I_3=\sqrt{2}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sec\left(u\right)}{\tan^2\left(u\right)+2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I_3=\sqrt{2}{\displaystyle\int}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{\cos\left(u\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sin^2\left(u\right)-2}\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

substitute $$v=\sin\left(u\right)$$

$$I_3=-\sqrt{2}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{v^2-2}\,\mathrm{d}v$$

$$I_3=-\sqrt{2}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v$$

$$I_3=-\sqrt{2}{\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}v$$

you can easily solve it 
$$I_3=-\sqrt{2}\big(\dfrac{\ln\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\big)$$

$$I_3=-\sqrt{2}\big(\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(u\right)+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(u\right)-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\big)$$
$$I_3=\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(u\right)+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(u\right)-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}$$

undo the substituion $$u=\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)$$

$$I_3=\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}$$

plug back $I_2$ AND $I_3$

$$I_1=\sqrt{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{2x^2+1}+\sqrt{2}x\right)-\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}+\sqrt{2}\right)+\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}-\sqrt{2}\right)$$

$$I=-\sqrt{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{2x^2+1}+\sqrt{2}x\right)+\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}+1\right)-\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}-1\right)+x\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)+C$$